# Downgrade to older version of Keynote

Tags: keynote

I just bought a new iMac with Keynote version 6.5.3. The company I do business with has Keynote 6.2.2. i am told they are incompatible. The company will not upgrade. Can I downgrade? If so, how?

Comment: This might be a workaround for you, saving as a package instead of a single file will allow it to be opened in an earlier version.  Ignore the first part about file size and look near the end of the support document at "Choose Use Package if:"   Have a look at: [Save documents as a package or a single file in iWork for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202887)

Comment: I think there are two possible answers: use pirate soft or buy some copies of iWork 09 as discussed here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569096?start=0&tstart=0